# Send email after 100 webform submissions

Tags: rules, webforms

I'd like to be able to send an email to the nth person (or every n people) that submit a specific webform. I've tried utilizing rules for this, but I can't seem to expose webform submission data to rules (using submission id). Any thoughts on how this could work through rules? Any suggestions for alternatives?

Comment: if you are able to code it by your self, i could give you an algorithm

Comment: I'm not very great with hooks but I can give it a shot. I'd figure I would just take the modulus of the submission ID, like: if(sid%n = 0)...Not sure if that is the best way to solve this or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules) ?

This should expose webform results to rules, then create a new rule with conditions "if submission ID is 100, 200 etc" then... action: Send email.

You would either need a way to find the nth of 100, or depending on how many submissions you are expecting, just check against a comma separated list, eg "100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200" etc

Comment: I do have webform rules enabled, but I cannot seem to find anything allowing me to access the submission ID. The rule is set up to fire after a webform has been submitted, but any sort of condition I put in doesn't allow for the submission ID to be accessed.

Comment: Sometimes to use the results of a field when using entities, you have to first use a condition "Entity has field" and then select the field you want to use.  There may be something similar with Webform Rules?

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't able to get any of the tokens to show up even after adding a field via "Entity has field". I'm able to do data comparison on the data of the submission (through the [data] token), but I'm unable to access any of the specific options of [data] (like [data:sid]).

Answer (score 1):

in [hook_webform_submission()](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_submission_insert/7) there is a variable `$submission`. So all you need to do is to implement this hook in your custom module and check for `$submission->sid` accordingly to your wisches.

If condition matches: [drupal_mail()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7)

Answer (score 0):

Use rules to add +1 to an integer field on a solitary node when a web form is submitted. Have another rule that fires when a webform is submitted and that integer field is equal to 100.

Use that rule to send an email and reset the integer to 0.